# MySQL: How can I count and limit the number of post submitted by the user every hour?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently building a website where user can post(like a tweet on twitter), but I want to limit the number of post a user can submit on the website every hour.

This is what I have coded so far and it outputs the total number of post a user have.

```
$counter = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS post_userID FROM post");
$num = mysql_fetch_array($counter);
$count = $num["post_userID"];
echo("$count");

if($count > 2) {
    echo("You have exceeded the posting limits, please try again in 24 hours");
}
```

MY POST TABLE

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| postID     |int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_userID|int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| message    |VARCHAR(140)| NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time       |datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As you can see, I have a time(datetime) stored on my database and it holds the time when the post was submitted.

EXAMPLE:

```
+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| postID     |post_userID | message    | time     |
+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| 1          |    25      | Hello Mike |1413620228| 
| 2          |    26      | Hi John!   |1413620332|
+------------+------------+------------+----------+
```

Oh btw, my server type is MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be:

```
select count(*) from post
  where post_userID = 25
    and time >= date_add(now(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR);
```

This will give you the number of posts for the user in the past hour.

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53a42/6)

Comment: I just edited a few to adapt your code to mine and I got it working :) I can't vote up your answer because I don't have enough reputation score yet but I will choose this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you have a `users` table. Create a column in the users table called `last_post_submit_time` and then whenever a user submits the post save that time in it. Finally whenever a user submits a post check if the `current time - it's last_post_submit_time >= one hour`. I hope you get it...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply divide the timestamp by 3600 and round it to integer, something like this:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(time/3600) AS hours_since_epoch
FROM
    posts
WHERE
    port_userID = <user> AND hours_since_epoch = ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())/3600)
```

This will return you the list posts user posted this hour (roughly).

Another way is to see how much the user has posted for the last hour:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    posts
WHERE
    port_userID = <user> AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 3600
```